# Deleted the DB2 Service Credentials. Created new credentials. New username and password not recognized for connection

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

#I'm using **IBM DB2** on the cloud service (lite) of IBM. I deleted the **DB2 Service** Credentials but I didn't get to save the original password and username. I deleted that credential and created a new one. But using the **ibm_db** commands from python notebooks and sql to connect to the database, an error occurs:

> SQLCODE=-30082ct:  [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001

I've tried repeatedly deleting and creating new service credentials but same error occurs. Not sure if I need the original or something. Is there a way to implement the password change without access to the original?

---

I use the following python code using a jupyter notebook. I assign the dsn_driver and others as a string e.g. dsn_uid = "abc1234".

```
import ibm_db

    dsn = (
        "DRIVER={0};"
        "DATABASE={1};"
        "HOSTNAME={2};"
        "PORT={3};"
        "PROTOCOL={4};"
        "UID={5};"
        "PWD={6};"
        "SECURITY={7};").format(dsn_driver, dsn_database, dsn_hostname, dsn_port, dsn_protocol, dsn_uid, dsn_pwd,dsn_security)
    
    try:
        conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
        print ("Connected to database: ", dsn_database, "as user: ", dsn_uid, "on host: ", dsn_hostname)
    
    except:
        print ("Unable to connect: ", ibm_db.conn_errormsg() )
```

RESULTS:

Comment: You probably have Db2 on Cloud. What service plan? How did you connect? Is this Python? Somehow your post is incomplete. Please edit and add

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning python and IBM DB2, so I wasnt sure what I needed to include. Hopefully what I added in the edits helped. Thank you.

Comment: Delete all the service credentials in your lite plan. Then create one new set of credentials and use that one. Your dsn or connection URI should include PROTOCOL=TCPIP;SECURITY=SSL;

Comment: Ive already done those steps. Having a different protocol and security results in a different error. The same error still occurs (reason 24).

Comment: Ive already done those steps, as mentioned ive deleted all of them and created new ones repeatedly. Even refreshing the DB and logging out repeatedly between steps. The same error still occurs (reason 24). Also,  a different error shows up if it were the protocol or security being the issue (I've tried fiddling with it before posting here). My current hypothesis is that it's not accepting the 'password change' when a new credential is made? Im not sure right now. @data_henrik

Comment: Or that you have to wait until a password change has been propagated. I saw that error few days ago, but resolved it while working on https://blog.4loeser.net/2021/10/db2-cloud-credentials-database-connection.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I was getting frustrated because been trying to solve it for several hours, will update later this week if same error still occurs.

Comment: @data_henrik It's been a week and the same error still occurs. I dont want to have to reupload everything in my database. And customer service of IBM has not been useful. I dont know what to do anymore.

Comment: update: I waited a month and the password change still hasnt set in. Had to delete the entire data base